# How can I replace a section on a page with another section on an anchor click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have a tasks listing on the right side of a page. On the other side, there is a map shown inside a `div`. I want to click on one of the tasks and get there details to replace map's `div`. After clicking in a link, when I refresh, I should still get the task details, not the map. Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show_task_detail").click(function() {
    $("#details").show();
    $("#browse_tasks_map").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action task-detail-link " data-url="/task-details" data-id="{{ $post->id }}" id="show_task_detail"><input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{$post->id}}" />Post title</a>
<div id="browse_tasks_map" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"></div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 task-detail-data" style="display: none;" id="details"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the addClass method of [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var hash = window.location.hash.split("#");
    if (hash.indexOf('show-details') > -1 ) {
        $("#details").addClass('show');
        $("#browse_tasks_map").addClass('hidden');
    }

    $("#show_task_detail").click(function () {
        $("#details").addClass('show');
        $("#browse_tasks_map").addClass('hidden');
        window.location.hash = "show-details";
    });
});
```

Where the CSS content would be,

```
.show {
    display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: @NomanCH updated the snippet and added multi hash support. Please check again.

Comment: The edited code worked but there is a small issue. It shows `map` div while reloading page. When loading is completed it shows required details

Comment: You can hide it at first using an extra class and the maps container ( in html ) then on reload by checking whether there's a hash or not you can show or hide it.

Answer (score 0):

1. When clicking the link, set the anchor part of the URL
2. When rendering the page, check the URL for the anchor tag

   ```
   function showDetails()
   {
       $("#details").show();
       $("#browse_tasks_map").hide();
   }

   $(document).ready(function()
   {
       if (document.hash == 'details')
       {
           showDetails();
       }
       $("#show_task_detail").click(function ()
       {
           showDetails();
           document.location.hash = 'details'
       });
   });
   ```